# Running example code from Tensorflow documentation, pertaining to Tensorflow-Federated, results in AttributeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to run the code given by Tensorflow in their official documentation, pertaining to Tensorflow-Federated. The code is as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

training_process = tff.learning.algorithms.build_weighted_fed_avg(get_dense_nn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.Sequential.SGD(learning_rate=client_lr),                                                                 server_optimizer_fn=lambda:tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=server_lr))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'

Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Is your python version 3.9 or later? As per the documentation page 
[Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlsQS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `tensorflow_federated.python.learning.from_keras_model` is attempting to be used, however this API does not exist.

In newer versions of TensorFlow Federated, the API has moved to [`tff.learning.models.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/models/from_keras_model).